# Django unicode method not working

Tags: django, python-2.7, unicode

I am following the app tutorial on the Django website and using ***Python 2.7.5*** with ***Django 1.8***. It suggests Python 2.7 users to include a **unicode** method in the models.py file to return readable output in the python shell.

## I have added the unicode method into the Question and Choice classes as so:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.util.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%i" % self.question_text

    def __str__(self):
        return question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%i" % self.choice_text
    def __str__(self):
        return choice_text
```

***This is my output from the python shell:***

```
from polls.models import Question, Choice
>>> Question.objects.all()
[<Question: Question object>]
>>>
```

***When it really should be this:***

```
>>> Question.objects.all()
[<Question: What's up?>]
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: Is the indentation same as in your code or is it wrong here? The unicode function is outside your class according to the question

Comment: Sorry! I had correct indentation in my file, however, it changed when it pasted it on here.

Answer (score 4):

Neither the `was_published_recently` nor the `__unicode__` method are within the Question class. Indentation is significant: make sure they are indented to the same level as the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should define also a `__str__` method. `__unicode__` will be used for explicit unicode calls.

And it's better to use `python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator from `django.utils.encoding` and you will define only the `__str__` method.

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class A(object):
    def __str__(self):
        # your code
```

Also this method it's compatible with python3 as well.

Comment: It is still not working. I added it like this and even restarted the python shell.        @Akisame
            `def __str__(self):
                return question_text`

Answer (score 0):

I've found out how to do it properly (I'm following the tutorial using python 2.7.11 and django 1.9.2 in a virtualenv):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.question_text)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.choice_text)
```

Now from the base of your project directory run the manage.py file like so:

```
$ python manage.py shell
```

This loads up IPython but sets all the proper environment variables for you so  it is easy to import your app (let's say we called it 'polls' which is what the tutorial called it I believe). Now let's try it out, from 
the IPython interpreter we just invoked with manage.py:

```
>>> from polls.models import Question, Choice
>>> Question.objects.all()
[]
>>> q = Question(question_text="I am now unicode!")
>>> q.save()
>>> Question.objects.all()
[<Question: I am now unicode!>]
```